# Looking for an OpenEV replacement, i.e a fast geotiff viewer

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, viewer, openev

I have in the past used OpenEV to have a fast preview of geotiff files. I tried to install it in Ubuntu 16.04, but it isn't in the ubuntu-gis ppa nor could I find another simple way to install it. The software seems to be abandoned. I know I can also pipe raster files into qgis, but qgis is often too heavy for a quick look and other Image viewers (e.g. Eye of Gnome) often struggle with geotiff files. 
So i was wondering if there is a simple FLOSS alternative for openEV that can be used in newer versions of Ubuntu and can be used in the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick has a nice simple tool to display images (including geotiff) from the command line:

```
display your_image_file
```

[image: geotiff in image magick display tool]

Use left mouse button to display command window, right mouse button to display popup menu. There is a *Pan icon* overview window to pan to a part of the image.
To install imagemagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: This just gives me "IMDisplayDoc function [DoReadImage] reported a warning" about the GeoTIFF tags.

Comment: Do you get this message for all tif images? It may be a faulty tif file.

Comment: All TIFF files from JAXA's ALOS (30m) dataset. QGIS loads them fine, so that's a strong sign that they're not faulty.